# Is it possible to have a shortcut to create bookmarks in Pages?

Tags: macos, safari, pages, iwork

In Apple Safari the `command-d` creates bookmarks. I would like to have it in Apple Pages.

Is it possible to have a shortcut to create bookmarks in Pages?

I know `command-k` but its for linking to already existing bookmarks.

Comment: Bookmarks are basically paragraph style, so you "set" them by applying a specific style (title, heading 1 etc) to a paragraph. So are you looking how to assign paragraph styles via the keyboard, or are you asking about something else?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for creating Bookmarks in Pages is: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

See the `Insert` menu list for details.

[image]